# Rem font size is different in the frontend and block editor

Tags: block-editor, fonts

I am building a theme, and same rem font size is different on frontend and in block editor.

I understand this is because the root element font size is different, but when I load my CSS in the admin backend to set my own root font size, `body` and `html` tags in the CSS gets replaced with the `.editor-styles-wrapper`

Instead of

```
html,
body {
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

I get:

```
.editor-styles-wrapper,
.editor-styles-wrapper {
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

How this can be solved?
Is there another way to adjust the block editor root font size?